# jQuery getJSON How to read sended parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax

Example :

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com'
jQuery.getJSON(url,
  {
   order:1, 
   value:2
  }).done(function(data){
    //how to get read sended parameter 1
    console.log(this.order) //--> i want return 1;
    //how to get read sended parameter 2
    console.log(this.value) //--> i want return 2
    //how to get read all sended parameters ?
    console.log(this.getSendedAllParameters) // i want return {order:1,value:2}
})
```

how to get order and value in done function?

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just can do

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com'



var d = {order:1, value:2};

jQuery.getJSON(url,d)
.done( 
    (function(sendedData){
        return function(data){
            console.log(sendedData.order);
            console.log(sendedData.value);
            console.log(sendedData);
        };
    })(d) 
)
```

A closure allow you to save the current state of a variable.

Comment: Is not there another way?

Comment: why do you want an other way ? the callback is only giving the result back

Comment: You really should give us more details when asking on StackOverflow

Comment: thank you. i can do. But not respectively in "for". i get mixed... :]